# PHP script gets downloaded each time

Tags: apache

**Newbie in Servers**
The PHP script in the action attribute get downloaded each time i submit the form.

```
<form action="action.php" method="POST">
```

The form is in *register.html* . Files *action.php* and *register.html* are both in the same directory /var/www/html which is my current root directory after I installed lamp server. I have another php file containing phpinfo() function which gets executed properly but action.php doesn't work.

My **action.php** script:

```
<?php

    echo $_POST['name'];

?>
```

My **register.html** file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        <title>A Simple form</title>
    </head> 

    <body>

        <form action="action.php" method="POST">

            Name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="name" ><br>
            Password:<br>
            <input type="password" name="password"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>

        </form> 


    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-i-can-see-it-on-source-code-of-page

Comment: @ali i already mentioned that a php file with phpinfo() function in the same directory is executing properly but action.php is not.

Comment: What platform are you on? Did you check the permissions on the files are identical if you are on a *nix system?

Comment: @Ali I am using linux mint 17 and have installed LAMP server.

Comment: Okay, I would compare permissions and owner/group between php files that work and don't work

Comment: Both the files( action.php and the file whiach contains phpinfo() ) have same permissions.

Comment: if you go to action.php by putting the url in the browser instead of submitting the form does it execute or download?

Comment: @Ali fortunately it executes :)

Comment: So in your `form action="action.php"` can  you use the full URL or use `/action.php` and see if it works then.

Comment: I used the full address of action.php. It still gets downloaded. When i open register.html in the browser , the url shows file:///var/www/html/register.html . Shouldn't it show localhost/... ?

Comment: Yes thats the problem. You need to open register.html by going to the apache url `http://localhost/ ... /register.html`. Do not open register.html by double-clicking the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP is opening register.html by double clicking the file, which leads to the file being opened by the browser with the `file://` protocol, instead of the `http://` protocol. Once opened with the `file://` protocol, the OS handles all form submissions and consequently action.php is also opened by the OS over the `file://` protocol. Apache is not involved and hence the issue.

To fix the issue, the initial file register.html (or index.html) must be opened over `http://localhost/ ... /register.html` by manually entering that url in the browser. This will now be served by Apache and any subsequent form submission and navigation will continue to be served by Apache, interpreting any PHP on the server-side in the process.

Comment: I opened register.html with localhost/register.html but after submitting I get 404 ( The requested URL /var/www/html/action.php was not found on this server. ) even though action.php is in same directory( /var/www/html/ ) as register.html .

Comment: Why is your URL `/var/www/html/action.php`? Can you update the original question with the latest version of the `register.html` file and the URL you are typing in the browser to get to it.

Comment: It's done. Will ask for help if something bad occurs. Thank you a lot for bearing it with me. :)